# Excel Formula: SUMIFS w/ Array - Convert to Formula with no Control-Shift-Enter?

Tags: arrays, excel, formula, sumifs

I am using an `=SUMIFS` formula to sum dollars by manufacturer as totals for groups of stores. The store IDs it checks are dynamic and will change often, and are pulled from the C column. I need to have this C column list change often for different many different groups of stores, and my formula should, per-vendor, sum the total dollars of what that whole group of specific stores sold

In the past, if I wanted the sum of multiple criteria's results, I would wrap my `=SUMIFS` in a `=SUM`, and then for a criteria field, enter an array constant like this `"{"example1","example2","example 3"}"`, etc.

I need those items in an array to be generated dynamically given what items exist in the C column. There may be hundreds, so typing manually is not an option.

---

Edit: I'm closer I think.

My formula is now:

=SUM(SUMIFS(DATA!$H:$H,DATA!$F:$F,Chico!$H20,DATA!$A:$A,TRANSPOSE($C$2:$C$715)))

What's in Transpose are the dynamic cells of my customer IDs.

Now, this =Transpose(), when I do a Control-Shift-Enter and wait a second, it appears to convert to an array formula, and it works! However this is not viable hundreds of times over and over. What I believe I most need assistance with is converting this formula to a properly utilize an array without it being a CSE formula.

Comment: Remove the `Transpose` function, replace `Sum` with `Sumproduct`.

Comment: Oh my god, that worked perfectly! Thanks so much!